# Rails query chokes on includes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

This query executes just fine:

```
p = PlayersToTeam.select("id").joins(:player).limit(10).order("players.FirstName")
```

This query causes my whole system to come to a screeching halt:

```
p = PlayersToTeam.select("id").includes(:player).limit(10).order("players.FirstName")
```

Here are the models:

```
class PlayersToTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :team

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :player
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players_to_teams
  has_many :teams, through: :players_to_teams
end
```

As far as I can tell, the `includes` does a `LEFT JOIN` and `joins` does an `INNER JOIN`.  The query spit out (for `joins`) from Rails is:

```
SELECT players_to_teams.id FROM `players_to_teams` INNER JOIN `players` ON `players`.`id` = `players_to_teams`.`player_id` ORDER BY players.FirstName LIMIT 10
```

Which executes just fine on the command line.

```
SELECT players_to_teams.id FROM `players_to_teams` LEFT JOIN `players` ON `players`.`id` = `players_to_teams`.`player_id` ORDER BY players.FirstName LIMIT 10
```

also executes just fine, it just takes twice as long.

Is there an efficient way I can sort the `players_to_teams` records via `players`? I have an index on `FirstName` for `players`.

**EDIT**

Turns out the query required heavy optimization to run even half decently.  Splitting the query was the best solution short of restructuring the Data or customizing the query

Comment: do all your join keys have indexes too?

Comment: When you say 'screeching halt', what exactly happens?

Comment: 'screeching halt' means when using the rails console, the terminal window just sits and spins until I ctrl-c it.  I usually give it a couple minutes before giving up on it.

Comment: So if the query generating via :joins works, what's stopping you from using that?

Comment: My view rely on associated columns (I pull the first name from the Player model).  If I don't do include, I hit the db for every row in a table of players, whereas if I use include, the db only gets hit once

Comment: You also might consider to split it into 2(3) queries. First - to get ids by sorting with joins. Second (which is inside contains 2 queries) - to get `PlayersToTeams` with `plaers` pre-loaded.

Comment: @MarkGuk - Can you show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also might consider to split it into 2(3) queries. First - to get ids by sorting with joins:

```
players_to_teams = PlayersToTeam.select("id").joins(:player).limit(10).order("players.FirstName")
```

Second (which is inside contains 2 queries) - to get `PlayersToTeams` with players pre-loaded.

```
players_to_teams = PlayersToTeam.include(:player).where(:id => players_to_teams.map(&:id))
```

So after that you will have fully initialized `players_to_teams` with players loaded and initialized.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that `include` will add a second db access to do the preloading. You should check what that one looks like (it should contain a big `IN` statement on the `player_ids` from `players_to_teams`).

As for how to avoid using `include`, if you just need the name from `players`, you can do it like this:

```
PlayersToTeam.select("players_to_teams.id, players.FirstName AS player_name").joins(:player).limit(10).order("players.FirstName")
```